# generate an FBX for smplx

Tags: python, graphics, 3d, pytorch, fbx

I need to generate an FBX file for maya from a .pkl pytorch model (smplx model).I'm quite new to 3d graphics(I know python and pytorch). My question is how can I get it done? like general steps. Also if something to read or topic to learn. I would really appreciate your help.

FBX for another similar model (smpl) is available from here in the downloads (you'll have to sign up) https://smpl.is.tue.mpg.de/ 
but I need smplx

Answer (score 1):

One of the easiest ways to consider for generating FBX for SMPL-X is to leverage SMPL-X Blender Plugin here: https://github.com/Meshcapade/SMPL_blender_addon.
Steps:

1. Launch Blender,
2. install SMPL-X Plugin,
3. load SMPL-X model using SMPL-X Plugin,
4. Export scene into FBX